# How do I get full RobotState from MoveIt? (in python)

Tags: ros, moveit, move-group, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do I get full RobotState from MoveIt? I could use `/joint_states` topic but there are more publishers of that, I would have to aggregate it somehow. There must be a simpler way, or am I wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/76570/how-do-i-get-full-robotstate-from-moveit?-(in-python)/) by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 801 on 2013-09-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the get_planning_scene service to query information about the various parts of MoveIt's planning scene.

Here is the detailed description: http://docs.ros.org/api/moveit_msgs/html/srv/GetPlanningScene.html

PS: For some reason that service was first not available for me. I had to manually add this capability in the move_group.launch:

```
<param name="capabilities" value="move_group/MoveGroupCartesianPathService                                                            [...]
                                  move_group/MoveGroupGetPlanningSceneService" />
```

---

Originally posted by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) with karma: 2062 on 2013-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Another option is to use the CurrentStateMonitor class:
http://moveit.ros.org/doxygen/classplanning__scene__monitor_1_1CurrentStateMonitor.html

Which allows you to monitor the current state easily.

Another way is to use the MoveGroupInterface class:
http://moveit.ros.org/doxygen/classmoveit_1_1planning__interface_1_1MoveGroup.html and calling getCurrentJointValues(). This function is a bit slow, as it will wait for a little while to receive messages so it can construct a full state. I recommend the first option if you need to get the state multiple times.

---

Originally posted by [isucan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1805/isucan/) with karma: 1055 on 2013-09-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [isucan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1805/isucan/) on 2013-09-05**:
I just saw the in python bit. I am working on a way to get a RobotState message (should be in today or tomorrow). At the moment, in RobotCommander you can call get_joint and get_link, which will give you some information about the state (joint position, transforms)